# Passing the VSCode display language to webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, iframe, webview, vscode-api

We can detect the vscode display language using vscode.env.language.
When we try to load any page in vscode webview it is still displaying the page in english even though my vscode.env.language is French.

How can we have this vscode display language passed to webview so that our page renders in french language.

Webview is opening in iframe. Basically i want to set the webview browser language to vscode display language.